# Android: error when making global function

Tags: java, android, function, global

i'm trying to make a global function class but it seems encountered error when i used it.
It works fine when i use it together in a class. actually every code that i put on Helper.java always make error. Anyone has any idea why?

### MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Helper application = (Helper) getApplication();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {

        } else {
            application.AlertWifi("No Internet Connection\nWould you like to turn on the wifi?");
        }
}
```

### Helper.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Application;

public class Helper extends Application {

public void AlertWifi(String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(msg);
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

                }
            });
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}

}
```

Comment: What error is it giving?Post the Logcat output.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:188)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)

Comment: @Rixwen that error is not happening  OnCreate on what you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//We will pass our Activity context
public void AlertWifi( Context ctx,String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(msg);
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}

}
```

And in Activity OnCreate

```
Helper application = (Helper) getApplication();
//this refer to our Activity
application.AlertWifi(this,"No Internet Connection\nWould you like to turn on the wifi?" );
```

plus in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application 
        android:name="Helper"
```

Here is Without flag. I am saving context as global weakrefernce. so inside Onclick i can get it back.

```
WeakReference<Context> wm;
    /**
     * 
     * @param ctx Activity context
     * @param msg Message that will be displayed
     */
public void AlertWifi( Context ctx,String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    wm=new WeakReference<Context>(ctx);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(msg);
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Context ctx=wm.get();
                    if(ctx!=null){
                    Intent i=new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      ctx.startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

Comment: if i may ask, why is it necessary to add the flag?

Comment: @Rixwen .It needed to call startActivity() from outside of an Activity context.

Comment: @Rixwen made it without flag.See if it foes work. it is better solution than previous

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Helper.this);

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope